# MongoDb sort on list of objects

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have some dummy data in my database. I'm trying to perform mongodb aggregation functions in order to sort based on a given title

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "fields" : [ { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Trish" }, { "title" : "zipcode", "value" : "01001" } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "fields" : [ { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Peter" }, { "title" : "zipcode", "value" : "00011" } ] }
```

The query that i'm able to come up with so far is this and the following is what mongodb returns.

db.test.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$fields"}, {$match: {"fields.title" : "firstName"}}, {$sort: {"fields.value" : 1} }])

```
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "fields" : { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Peter" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "fields" : { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Trish" } }
```

However the result I would the returned dataset should include the other object in the fields list like so. The main thing that I am trying to accomplish is being able to sort the documents based on a specific field title

```
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "fields" : [ { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Peter" }, { "title" : "zipcode", "value" : "00011" } ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "fields" : [ { "title" : "firstName", "value" : "Trish" }, { "title" : "zipcode", "value" : "01001" } ] }
```

Comment: let me know , you want sort docs according to specific value of `fields.title` ? for example sort `firstName`  ?

Comment: yeah i want to sort based on title to determine what order i want the _id to come out as but still want to include all other nested documents in the fields property

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the position of the fields, firstName always the first, and so on. You can sort by that. like this:

```js
db.test.find().sort({'fields.0.value': -1})
//or
db.test.find().sort({'fields.0.value': 1})
```